# LinkedIn API - Campaign Demographic data

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm looking to leverage the **LinkedIn API** to obtain the demographics data for a campaign in 'Campaign Manager'.

The current API call I have is returning the engagement metrics, but I can't seem to find anything in the official docs or otherwise regarding demographic data. Seems odd that there is a demographics view in the LinkedIn manager but nothing via the API.

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=15&dateRange.start.month=2&dateRange.start.year=2021&timeGranularity=ALL&campaigns[0]=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:${CAMPAIGN_ID}&fields=externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange,impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,pivot,pivotValue
```

As the documentation isn't very clear, I was wondering if anyone had managed to achieve this elsewhere?

Comment: Do you have already tried this pivot? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#reporting-microsoft-bing-locations